# A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'

Tags: cordova, sdk, android-ndk, ionic3

BUILD FAILED in 3s

cmd:

```
Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project 'CordovaLib'.

  > No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with pref
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--infout`.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

`[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess Cordova.`

```
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when updated Android NDK to version 18.
To fix this you should download Android NDK (Revision 17c) from 
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases
Then delete NDK using SDK Manager, and extract files to android-sdk-location/ndk-bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your NDK directory is not complete. You can download the NDK package from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/ separately and unzip it.

Then open the `toolchains` folder, compare it with the `android-sdk`->`ndk-bundle`->`toolchains` folder, find the missing folder and copy / paste it to your `ndk-bundle`, Recompiling your project should go well.

You can also see more discussions at thread: https://github.com/google/filament/issues/15