# A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'. > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath' : Ionic3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
```

**ionic cordova build/run android** not working. Always showing this error:

[image: this error].

It seems no error on project because it worked when copied to another system.

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717762/a-problem-occurred-configuring-project-cordovalib) and [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/a-problem-occurred-configuring-project-cordovalib-in-ionic-cordova/146123) but it is not working.

Comment: Try with this command: ```ionic build```

Comment: I need to build android apk..

Comment: Did you try these solutions here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994163/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-classpath#:~:text=Go%20to%20File%20%2D%3E%20Invalidate%20Caches,missing%20files%20for%20the%20project

Comment: tried..but no change

Comment: Try deleting your ```android``` folder, and generate it again.
If not working, 
Try using Capacitor,  ```ionic build``` then ```npx cap add android```, ```npx cap copy android```, ```npx cap open android```  (remove android folder first)